# Converting Varchar to Date PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Hi I have an issue i need to convert date values coming from table in Varchar format(example: 12/31/2013 00:00:00.000000) to date format (example: 12/31/2013) and there are multiple rows to be selected. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use TO_TIMESTAMP because this has fractional seconds. Example below.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('12/31/2013 00:00:00.000000', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
FROM DUAL
```